# iOS Swift: Collection View with paged scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Evening,

I have the current layout:

- a collection view paged with horizontal flow
- a single row on cells that have `width = collection view - 50.0`

**The problem:**

When i scroll to the next page the cell does not appear aligned with the collection view..

**The reason:**

the cell width did not cover the collection view width.

**How to Fix:**

I have no clue, i tried with didEndDragging delegate adding +50 on the content offset but it didn't work..

I've also tried this:

```
if scrollView == self.badgeCollectionView {
      print(scrollView.contentSize)
      let point =  scrollView.contentOffset                      
      let index = badgeCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point)
      self.badgeCollectionView.selectItem(at: index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: have you tried to set the cell size in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` like `CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)`?

Comment: yes of course..